# How to add a custom comment to any folder

Tags: windows-xp, comments

How do I add a custom comment to any folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If John T.'s suggestion is 'too complicated', you may use **[HOBComment ShellExtension](http://www.dr-hoiby.com/CommentExtXP/)**:

> HOBComment is a Windows Explorer shell
>   extention that enables you to
>   right-click to add a comment to a
>   folder; it will also allow to do the
>   same to add comments to files on your
>   NTFS partitions.

Also available: **[HOBComment Explorer Extension](http://www.dr-hoiby.com/CommentExt/index.php)** (GUI & command line)

[image]

Comment: @Jitendra vyas - you're welcome. btw, this also works for files which very handy too.

Comment: @Jitendra vyas - see my anser to this question: http://superuser.com/questions/103924/is-there-a-windows-program-that-will-log-a-reason-for-copying-a-file-to-a-folder

Comment: @Molly - What is the difference between HOBComment Shell Extension and Explorer Extension

Comment: @Jitendra vyas - you'll need the explorer extension if you want to add the "File/Folder Comment" column to windows explorer via View > Choose Details ... as seen in the screen shot my other answer

Answer (score 4):

- Right-click the folder and select Properties.
- From the **Properties** dialog box, select the **Customize** tab, and then click the **Change Icon** button.
- In the Change Icon dialog box, select an icon from the selections and click OK.
- Click OK to close the Properties dialog box.
- Open the folder, locate the **Desktop.ini** file, and double-click it.
- Add **InfoTip=** to the end of the Desktop.ini file and type your detailed description immediately after the = sign.
- Go to **File -> Save** and close Notepad.

You'll see your detailed pop-up description the next time you hover the mouse over that specific folder.

If you'd like to keep the normal folder icon, you can simply choose it from the selection when changing the icon, it is the exact same:

[image]

[image]

[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5587642.html)

Comment: can we have any simpler way than this?

Comment: This is the way Microsoft recommends: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776832%28VS.85%29.aspx . There are probably tools out there to automate it but it doesn't take very long unless you're doing tons of folders.

Comment: UserInfoTip is one piece of software that can do this, although it isn't free: http://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Shell-Replacements/UserInfoTip.shtml

Comment: in step 3 u mentioned "In the Change Icon dialog box, select an icon from the selections and click OK." but i don't want to change icon